# Unable to retrieve a specific value in MySQL while using a normal SELECT with nested SELECT using COUNT with CASE

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT GREATEST(Depressed, Non_depressed), Stat
    FROM (
        SELECT
        state AS Stat,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN state = "dep" then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Depressed,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN state = "sane" then 1 ELSE NULL END) as Non_depressed
        FROM phoneCallFeatures  
    ) 
AS Maximum
```

I am trying to retrieve the name of the state so I can know which of the two states is most recurrent.

My output is as following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a better way of phrasing your query:

```
SELECT state, COUNT(*) AS state_count
FROM phoneCallFeatures
WHERE state IN ('dep', 'sane')
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Just use `GROUP BY` and let MySQL worry about tallying records, which it is good at doing.

### Demo here

If you want to continue with your current approach, then the only problem is your selecting `stat` in the inner query.  This doesn't make sense, because `SUM()` is an aggregate function and it is not clear *which* `stat` value will be chosen.  In the query below, I use a `CASE` expression to compare the counts, and then present the appropriate label based on that.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Depressed > Non_depressed
            THEN 'depressed'
            ELSE 'non depressed' END AS stat,
       GREATEST(Depressed, Non_depressed) AS stat_count
FROM
(
    SELECT
        state AS Stat,
        SUM(CASE WHEN state = "dep"  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Depressed,
        SUM(CASE WHEN state = "sane" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Non_depressed
    FROM phoneCallFeatures  
) AS Maximum
```

Note that I replaced `COUNT()` with `SUM()`.  There is nothing wrong with `COUNT()` the way you have used it, since it will ignore `NULL` values, but `SUM()` seems more logical to me here.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast, Well I ran your first query and it gave me **Empty Result**. Your second query seemed so logical to me but gave me the opposite results with `stat_count` equal to 0.

Let me tell you what I have tried so far .. I had the same query work on another table I have, the thing is that I had `NULL` values in my 'phoneCallFeatures' table. I changed the rest of the values randomly to _dep_ and _sane_ and it worked by displaying the highest of those along the state name.

Comment: @AhmedHamed I suspect that your data is the problem.  Take one of the demos I gave, update with your data, and drop another comment if my queries are really still causing a problem for you.

Comment: I am going to do that right away. Thank you so much for your efforts

Comment: WOW thank you so much, it worked like a charm. while testing I changed the values of dep and sane into 0 and 1. God, feeling a bit dumb right now. Again much thanks. I will accept your answer.

Comment: One more question please, In the first query, If i am getting it right, I am getting the name of the state which has the maximum value repitition is that right ? idk if i did say it right .. please inlight me.

Comment: Correct.  Each name would be some status (i.e. `dep` or `sane`), along with its count.  As I wrote the query, only the status with the highest count will be returned.

Comment: Perfect, and this works for as many statuses the table contains. It is much better optimized comparing to the second query. Much thanks again.